# How many partitions does Spark create when a file is loaded from S3 bucket?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-s3, rdd

If the file is loaded from HDFS by default spark creates one partition per block. But how does spark decide partitions when a file is loaded from S3 bucket?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the code of `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits()`.

Block size depends on S3 file system implementation (see `FileStatus.getBlockSize()`). E.g. `S3AFileStatus` just set it equals to `0` (and then `FileInputFormat.computeSplitSize()` comes into play).

Also, you don't get splits if your InputFormat is not splittable :)

Comment: Please excuse my lack of knowledge on this, but how can I check these values for my cluster?

Answer (score 4):

Even when reading a file from an S3 bucket, Spark (by default) creates one partition per block i.e. total no of partitions = total-file-size / block-size.

The value of block size for S3 is available as a property in Hadoop's core-site.xml file which is used by Spark:

```
<property>
  <name>fs.s3a.block.size</name>
  <value>32M</value>
  <description>Block size to use when reading files using s3a: file system.
  </description>
</property>
```

Unlike HDFS, AWS S3 is not a file system. It is an object store. The S3A connector makes S3 look like a file system.

Please checkout the [documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/performance.html#For_large_data_uploads.2C_tune_the_block_size:_fs.s3a.block.size) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

By default spark will create partitions of size 64MB when reading from s3.
So a 100 MB file will be split into 2 partitions, 64MB and 36MB. An object having size less than or equal to 64 MB wont be split at all.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this?