# Spark writing/reading to/from S3 - Partition Size and Compression

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, gzip

I am doing an experiment to understand which file size behaves best with s3 and [EMR + Spark]

Input data :

```
Incompressible data: Random Bytes in files 
Total Data Size: 20GB  
Each folder has varying input file size: From 2MB To 4GB file size.
```

Cluster Specifications :

```
1 master + 4 nodes : C3.8xls
--driver-memory 5G \
--executor-memory 3G \
--executor-cores 2 \
--num-executors 60 \
```

Code :

```
scala> def time[R](block: => R): R = {
          val t0 = System.nanoTime()
          val result = block    // call-by-name
         val t1 = System.nanoTime()
          println("Elapsed time: " + (t1 - t0) + "ns")
          result
      }
time: [R](block: => R)R

scala> val inputFiles = time{sc.textFile("s3://bucket/folder/2mb-10240files-20gb/*/*")};
scala> val outputFiles = time {inputFiles.saveAsTextFile("s3://bucket/folder-out/2mb-10240files-20gb/")};
```

**Observations**

> - 2MB - 32MB: Most of the time is spent in opening file handles [Not    efficient]
> - 64MB till 1GB: Spark itself is launching 320 tasks for    all these file sizes, it's no longer the no of files in that bucket    with 20GB
>   data e.g. 512 MB files had 40 files to make 20gb data and    could
>   just have 40 tasks to be completed but instead, there were 320
>   tasks each dealing with 64MB data.
> - 4GB file size : 0 Bytes outputted    [Not able to handle in-memory /Data not even splittable ???]

**Questions**

> - Any default setting that forces input size to be dealt with to be     64MB ??
> - Since the data I am using is random bytes and is already compressed how is it splitting this data further? If it can split this data why is it not able to split file size of 4gb object file
>   size?
> - Why is compressed file size increased after uploading via spark? The 2MB compressed input file becomes 3.6 MB in the output bucket.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since it is not specified, I'm assuming usage of gzip and Spark 2.2 in my answer.

- **Any default setting that forces input size to be dealt with to be 64MB ??**

Yes, there is. Spark is a Hadoop project, and therefore treats S3 to be a block based file system even though it is an object based file system.
So the real question here is: which implementation of S3 file system are you using(s3a, s3n) etc. A similar question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37168716/how-many-partitions-does-spark-create-when-a-file-is-loaded-from-s3-bucket).

- **Since the data I am using is random bytes and is already compressed how is it splitting this data further? If it can split this data why is it not able to split file size of 4gb object file size?**

[Spark docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html) indicate that it is capable of reading compressed files:

> All of Spark’s file-based input methods, including textFile, support running on directories, compressed files, and wildcards as well. For example, you can use textFile("/my/directory"), textFile("/my/directory/.txt"), and textFile("/my/directory/.gz").

This means that your files were read quite easily and converted to a plaintext string for each line.

However, you are using compressed files. Assuming it is a non-splittable format such as gzip, the entire file is needed for de-compression. You are running with 3gb executors which can satisfy the needs of 4mb-1gb files quite well, but can't handle a file larger than 3gb at once (probably lesser after accounting for overhead).

Some further info can be found in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40492967/dealing-with-a-large-gzipped-file-in-spark). Details of splittable compression types can be found in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34209281/2996373).

- **Why is compressed file size increased after uploading via spark?The 2MB compressed input file becomes 3.6 MB in output bucket.**

As a corollary to the previous point, this means that spark has de-compressed the RDD while reading as plaintext. While re-uploading, it is no longer compressed. To compress, you can pass a compression codec as a parameter:

```
sc.saveAsTextFile("s3://path", classOf[org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec])
```

There are other compression formats available.

Comment: Thanks Ra41P for the answer, this was helpful :)